# Flutter implementing Shadertoy example with negative UV

Tags: flutter, glsl, shadertoy

I'm new to GLSL. I've used [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/image-manipulation-with-shaders-flutter-aa11027b4a4d) guide to manipulate my image via shaders.

The example in that page works fine for several ShaderToy examples but I've stumbled upon a simple one which I can't get it to work. This is the [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xt2XDy):

This is my Flutter shader frag file equivalent of that shader:

shader.frag

```
#include <flutter/runtime_effect.glsl>

out vec4 fragColor;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0; // Main image
uniform sampler2D iChannel1; // This is the noise
uniform vec2 uSize;
uniform float iTime;

vec2 iResolution;

vec2 drop(vec2 uv, vec2 pos, float r)
{
    pos.y = fract(pos.y);
    return (uv - pos) * exp(-pow(20.0 * length(uv - pos), 2.0));
}

void main() {
    iResolution = uSize;
    vec2 fragCoord = FlutterFragCoord();

    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec2 uv2 = vec2(uv.x * iResolution.x / iResolution.y, uv.y);

    vec2 d = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    const int n = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vec4 r = texture(iChannel1, vec2(float(i) / float(n), 0.5));
        vec2 pos = r.xy;
        pos.x *= 2.0; // iResolution.x / iResolution.y;
        pos.y += 10.0 * iTime * 0.02 * r.a;
        //pos.x += sin(t + r.z);
        d += 0.1 * drop(uv2.xy, pos, 0.03);
    }

    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, -uv.xy + d);
}
```

The output is no image. Just a plain single color. The last line of the shader `-uv.xy` is causing flutter to show a single color.
I've tried doing  `uv = 2.0 * uv - 1.0;` before the last line which makes the image appears 1/4 size and there are no animations.
There's also an option in Shadertoy for texture channel images called `vflip` which is off for this shader but for some [others](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tsccWr) that is on. Switching it off/on for this shader, doesn't simply flip the image but also changes the way the noise is rendered. I don't know who to implement that in Flutter.

I don't think my Flutter side is wrong since it is working for other shaders. It is almost a copy-paste of the tutorial linked above. Just added one more `sampler2D` for the noise image.

Any help is greatly appreciated!